# Append array into multidimensional array using key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've two multidimensional arrays and I need merge both by specific key. I tried with array_merge_recursive and array_search with poor results.

So,

main arrays:

```
Array
(
    [group] => Array
        (
            [subgroup] => Array
                (
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [item 1] => web development
                            [item 2] => dba
                            [item 3] => qa
                        )
                )
        )
)

/* ------------ */

Array (
        [item 1] =>  Array
            (
                [User 1] => Array
                    (
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => conexion_1624
                                [name] => Jhon Doe 
                            )
                    )
                [User 2] => Array
                    (
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => conexion_2001
                                [name] => Alice and Bob
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

expected result:

```
Array
(
    [group] => Array
        (
            [subgroup] => Array
                (
                    [items] => Array
                        (
                            [item 1] => Array
                                (
                                    [User 1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [properties] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => conexion_1624
                                                    [name] => Jhon Doe  
                                                )
                                        )
                                    [User 2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [properties] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => conexion_2001
                                                    [name] => Alice and Bob
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [item 2] => dba
                            [item 3] => qa
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: ie you want replace value of item1 in the 1st array by value of item1 in the 2st array ?

Comment: Good Day @splash58 that´s correct. i need put all values from second array (all users) into **item 1** key in first array. i try using `array_merge_recursive($arr1, $arr2)` but just append second one but not in the right sub key

Comment: if you will need  to find it, use the code `array_walk_recursive (
          $the1nd , 
          function($v, $k, $the2nd) {
              if(isset($the2nd[$k])) $v = $the2nd[$k];
          },  
          $the2nd);`

Comment: this is that why i lookin for, Thanks @splash58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arrays structures are not changed

```
foreach($the2nd as $key => $item) 
  $the1st['group']['subgroup']['items'][$key] = $item;
```

**UPDATE** due to discussion in comments

if in the 1st array items may be not on the same level, such code will find them

```
array_walk_recursive ( 
     $the1nd , 
     function($v, $k, $the2nd) { if(isset($the2nd[$k])) $v = $the2nd[$k]; },
     $the2nd);
```

Comment: The Structure may change because is from an database query the "Item 1" key is static.. so i try to find the key using search function and then append the other array.

Comment: in 2nd array `item 1` ... is upper level keys. if in 2nd items in path `$the1st['group']['subgroup']['items']` both codes shalll work regardless of data changing. If path may be not the same, what we will find - `item 1` ?

Comment: It's because I was looking for a function that will return me the path looking for the key to make the merge, sometimes it is not in 4 level.

Comment: i write in comment to question code for changed structure case

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you the result you are looking for.

```
$result = array_merge($array1['group']['subgroup']['items'], $array2);
```